# Recovery data from Android(internal storage)

Tags: android, data-recovery

I have an Android phone with android version 4.4.2 . I deleted some files and i really need them. ON MSC USB connection i see only the sd card (with PhotoRec). What solutions exist to recover data from internal memory?
Or exists API from Android to read unallocated memory?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few methods of recovering internal memory. As you know, Android doesn't allow direct access to internal memory. A fellow member on XDA built a guide on how to extract a RAW image of internal memory and convert it to a usable partition. [Link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/guide-internal-memory-data-recovery-yes-t1994705)

This is another article that uses the same method, just different instructions: [Link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2143188)

**Edit:** To root the Xperia E3, some have confirmed that towelroot (tr.apk) rooted it, also try Framaroot and Kingo root. These are all one-click non-invasive methods. There is no guarantee that one will or won't work. There are also some specific Xperia rooting methods, [this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2784900&page=1) is non-invasive, but not specific to the E3. [This one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-e3/general/root-e3-t2964845) is specific to the E3 and is invasive! It will wipe data. However, since you are already missing the files, it should not make it worse than it already is. It's not even on the same partition. So, you should be fine restorting to this method if you have to. Let's just say that the rewards exceed the risks.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, but this two articles say that i need a rooted android phone: "try to root with a non-destructive method as this appears to protect those who must root from wiping the device data a second time". Where i can find this method, non-destructive ?

Comment: There are hundreds of non-invasive rooting methods out there. It all comes down to the phone model. What's your brand/model?

Comment: Xperia E3. But this(http://developer.sonymobile.com/unlockbootloader/unlock-yourboot-loader/) say that i cannot root if Bootloader unlock allowed says NO. And some people say that it's posible.

Comment: Lol, no manufacturer on the face of the earth will admit their devices can be rooted. I have edited my answer above to include some rooting methods.

Comment: Thanks. You say that even if i use invasive method(and it will wipe date) my deleted files remains because it's not on the same partition?

Comment: Yes. Basically even if you re-flash the firmware, means that you flash the /system partition, it clears the partition table for the /sdcard and /mnt directories but doesn't actually go through and write 0's through the entire 2GB+ dataspace your files are stored in. For example, I bricked my Note 2 when trying to write a recovery partition, when I was a newbie. There was no way to boot the phone at all, as Verizon locked everything out. I could get into flashing mode, however. I flashed stock firmware and to my surprise, everything was still there untouched! Different brand, same concept.

Comment: With this http://towelroot.org/  where .apk has 148 KB and i get the message "App not installed". With this https://towelroot.com/ where .apk has 109 KB I get a message like this 'this phone isn't currently supported'. What do advise me?To try Framaroot and Kingo root(in forums i didn't see that this works) ?

Comment: or to try directly this :
The only chance for D2203 with Bootloader Unlock Allowed: No
is this http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=59544048&postcount=28
More accurate this link http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-e3/general/root-xperia-e3-d2203-locked-bl-t3075559 . I saw the answer :"Success! Hitted THANKS!
Confirmed: In service menu I have: Bootloader unlock allowed: No "

Comment: I don't have much memory to install/uninstall another apps (like Framaroot).
So if you agree with me what are the consequences in using this solution(http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-e3/general/root-xperia-e3-d2203-locked-bl-t3075559)? I have a chance to recovery my data?

Comment: Nice article you found, by the way. I can't tell you *for sure* how you should proceed, so I asked the author on XDA what he thought. You can read & monitor my post here: [root xperia e3 locked bl](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-e3/general/root-xperia-e3-d2203-locked-bl-t3075559/page3)  I had some questions for him on his exploit.

Comment: I need to recovery data from an app. This(http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/android-partitions-explained-boot-system-recovery-data-cache-misc/) say that the data partition contains my apps. I have a very small chance but it's the only way. Before i begin: 1) "0. Make backup". Backup can be made with Sony Pc Companion ?  2)usb mtp or msc ?

Comment: "It wipe /data and flash it with files in userdata.sin " => This means to replace ~1GB ?  (I cannot make account at xda-developers. This is why i post here.)

Comment: Yeah that's what I was questioning. A raw sin file would have to literally be 1GB of empty blocks to fill up 1GB of space, according to how the file is structured. The file contains a header, metadata, and 1s and 0s. I'm pretty sure it will be safe. it is a user installed app you're trying to extract, right?

Comment: I do not know what drivers to install. C:\Flashtool\drivers\Flashtool-drivers.exe.  I dont see Xperia. I need to select all?

Comment: I installed this (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) and i click normal(not CWM) and i get err : "SuperSU Binary Update Failed error". What  can i do?

Comment: Try Superuser by ChainsDD [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noshufou.android.su)

Comment: I got stuck at the end.Please, help me.I have the Tab 'Apps' but is empty(i just rooted). On Tab 'Info' I have: elite not installed(get elite). su binary v2.00:SUPERSU(0) ,with red '-rwxr-xr-x', with green 'root root' and '/sytem/xbin/su'. And tow unchecked: temp unroot, ota survival. And when i click su binary v2.00:SUPERSU(0) it say Downloading manifest failed with button Try again.  What is this app?

Comment: You don't have to update the binaries. It's all set. Default settings are ok. Move on to installing BusyBox.

Comment: I installed the BusyBox but when i open it says 'Install' "Uninstall". After a while(i have not clicked on anything) i get the err 'There was a problem opening a shell with root access. This is either being caused by superuser/supersu or by a device that is improperly rooted. Try removing the superuser/supersu permissions, uninstalling this app' like this (forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2143406) It's good this tutorial androidgadgematic.com/2012/08/…?

Comment: If yes then "Boot into the recovery mode." How? Turn off phone, connect to PC with USB and 
press volume down?

and From tutorial of recovery data "Connect the phone in ADB mode" What is ADB mode?

Comment: I stuck to 'Boot into the recovery mode' .It's the third step. What means recovery mode?

Comment: All you have to do is hold one of your volume buttons down while turning it on, holding it until it shows "recovery console".

Comment: It only Vibration 2 or 3 times and continued so until no longer hold the buttons pressed,(this with Volume  +). with volume - it turn on normally

Comment: Try home button & volume up/down

Comment: Xperia E3 have no recovery mode(https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-E3-E3-Dual/Xperia-E3-recovery-Mode/m-p/971082#U971082) Can i do with FlashTool ? i need to copy supersu zip in .flashTool\firmwares?

Comment: Hey, just saw this announcement in the news. Take a look: [Sony bootloaders - Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2015/05/03/sony-helps-with-installing-custom-roms/)